# Random characters when retrieving private/public KEY (OpenSSL) from file

Tags: openssl, elliptic-curve

I am trying to make a program that after it generates a public/private key pair using OppenSSL EC function EC_KEY_generate_key store them in separate files and retrieve them to generate an ECDH KEY.

My problem is that although I store them correctly(without any additional character), when I read the file and try to convert the hex characters to BIGNUM a character '04' or '00' randomly appears (or even sometimes not). So when I try to set the public/private keys and check the whole key, it fails. Could anyone help me with this issue? Could the key checking failure be caused by these characters or they are normal?

Here is my code that generates/stores the private key(the public one is the same):

```
    EC_KEY *b = NULL;
const BIGNUM *ppriv_b;
FILE *claveprivb;
const EC_GROUP *group;

b = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime192v1);
group = EC_KEY_get0_group(b);

EC_KEY_generate_key(b);
    claveprivb = fopen("/tmp/mnt/claveprivb", "w+");
    ppriv_b = EC_KEY_get0_private_key(b);
if ((ppriv_b != NULL)) 
    BN_print_fp(claveprivb,ppriv_b);
    fclose(claveprivb);

    //Afterwards do the same with the public key
```

And here is my code for retrieving the Private key:

```
    int i, s, blen, bout, ret = 0;
unsigned char *bbuf;
FILE *clavepriv, *clavetotalb;
const char cpriv_string[PRIVATE_KEY_SIZE];
BIGNUM *priv;
EC_KEY *b = NULL;
const EC_GROUP *groupb;

    b = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime192v1);
groupb = EC_KEY_get0_group(b);
    //Open the file with the hexadecimals (PRIVATE KEY)
    clavepriv = fopen("/tmp/mnt/claveprivb", "r");
kk2 = fread(&cpriv_string, sizeof(char), PRIVATE_KEY_SIZE, clavepriv);

priv = BN_new();
    //THIS FUNCTION (HEX2BN) GENERATES THE RANDOM CHARACTER: 
kk2 = BN_hex2bn(&priv, cpriv_string);
ret = EC_KEY_set_private_key(b, priv);

    //HERE I retrieve the public key by the same way and set it into EC_KEY b,
    //the same random character appears in the public key

    if (!EC_KEY_check_key(b)) {
    printf("EC_KEY_check_key failed\n");
} else {
    printf("Key verified OK\n");
}
    //It fails when try to check it.

int k;
clavetotalb = fopen("/tmp/mnt/clavetotalb", "w+");
k = EC_KEY_print_fp(clavetotalb, b, 0);

bout = ECDH_compute_key(bbuf, blen, EC_KEY_get0_public_key(b), b,
        KDF1_SHA1);
```

Any advise would be very appreciated!!!!Thanks!!!

After I read the answering post, I have tried to use these methods to decode and encode the public key, but by the time I try to compute the ECDH key I get a segmentation fault. The target of my program is to generate two EC keys, write them into several files and then, retrieve them and compute an ECDH key with them. This is the list of the things I change from my original program in the first thread, please tell me if something is wrong:

```
* Generate EC key (public & private)
* Decode the private key with i2d_ECPrivatekey()
* Decode the public key with i2o_ECPublickey()
* Write them into several files.
* Read the file with the public key.
* Encode it with o2i_ECPublickey()
* Read the file with the private key.
* Encode it with d2i_ECPrivatekey().
* Compute the ECDH key.(Here is where I get the segmentation fault)
```

I am quite fed up with this OpenSSL library...it is so inaccessible for first-time users...

Comment: did you find why you couldn't get the private key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An EC public key is *not* an integer; it is a *curve point* which can be thought as a *pair of* integers. Those two integers are the point coordinates (often called *X* and *Y*).

Some notations: the curve is defined in a finite field. The finite field elements can be mapped to integers from *0* to *q-1*, where *q* is the field size (in the case of the curve you use, *q* is a prime integer slightly lower than *2<sup>192</sup>*). Let *n* be the size in *bytes* of *q-1*: this is the size of the unsigned big endian representation of *q-1*, namely the integer such that *2<sup>8(n-1)</sup> <= q-1 < 2<sup>8n</sup>*. For your curve, *n = 24*.

With these notations, the standard representation of a curve point consists in exactly *1+2n* bytes, which are, in that order:

- the byte of value 0x04
- the unsigned big endian representation of *x* over *n* bytes
- the unsigned big endian representation of *y* over *n* bytes

So this explains your '0x04' extra byte; also, since *x* and *y* are to be encoded over exactly *n* bytes, this may force the inclusion extra '0x00' bytes, in case their actual value turns out to be smaller than *2<sup>8(n-1)</sup>* (with your curve, this should be the case, on average, for about 1/128th of public keys).

There are other variants of this representation (*compressed*, in which the total size is *1+n* and the first byte is 0x02 or 0x03, and *hybrid*, of size *1+2n*, where the first byte is 0x06 or 0x07), but they are considered as optional in the ECDSA standard (X9.62-2005) and rumor has it that the compressed format is patented.

Bottom-line: if you want to encode and decode EC public keys, you should look at `o2i_ECPublicKey()` and `i2o_ECPublicKey()`, and handle them as sequence of arbitrary bytes, not encoded integers.

Comment: any idea for why the private key can't be correctly accessed with ec_key_get0_private_key?